# Registering user in an app: Logic workflow

Tags: android, authentication

I am programming a mobile app and I´ve got a brief doubt regarding the register aspects:

When an user just registers himself within the app, should I bring them to the application itself as if they were logged in, or should I force them to log in?
Please, give any source that can be taken as a good practise provider.

**Please note the question is not opinion based**, as long as I am requesting a contrasted, community-accepted answer and not opinion.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: After researching for a while, I found that many services log you in when you register (i.e GMail). Still not being able to find a proper explanation for this, or the best practises approved by the community.

Comment: I think you should make it in such as way that after registration user is logged in automatically. But once user uninstalls your app or logs out of your app, then you should display login page when the app is opened. Opening login page after successful registration is sometimes annoying to the users, especially when login is OTP based.

Comment: I think you´re right my friend. Have you found any link reforcing our thoughts?

Comment: I did'nt try to find any source for this, I commented what I think should be logical. We can wait for someone to answer your question more accurately.

Comment: @AlokGupta After researching a little bit more, I don´t think there will be an "official" guidance for this, so as long as you´re happy writing that as an answer, I´ll be happy to accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make it in such as way that after registration user is logged in automatically. But once user uninstalls your app or logs out of your app, then you should display login page when the app is opened. Opening login page after successful registration is sometimes annoying to the users, especially when login is OTP based.